Should an HVAC technician be expected to examine the coil when called to troubleshoot a condensate drain?
12 month old HVAC pan was full, with slow drip. Installer found drain clogged,cleared it and emptied the pan.
The following day the ceiling collapsed. Installer returned and found a lot of debris at the bottom of the coil, blocking drainage,and an again full drain pain. (I think debris was due to the contractor not protecting the system during rehab.) What he didn't notice was that the drain line had come apart, presumably when he had cleaned out the drain line on the previous day.
I’m wondering if its reasonable for me to have expected the HVAC installer and repair person (same guy) to:

Open the machine to see if there was anything wrong with the coil, when he was hired called to troubleshoot and repair the full pan, and found the line clogged?

Should he be responsible for the drain line, (which he connected one year ago) coming apart when he cleaned it out? (Either he didn't connect it properly or he used so much pressure that it came apart.)


I feel that the consequenses of this leak should be on him and his insurance company but I want to be reasonable. Am I missing something?
Please note: The system worked for 8 months, post contractor's failure to protect the coils. It then went from a slow drip one day, to being so saturated that the ceiling in two rooms collapsed, in less than 24 hours, during which he was the only one messing with the system.





Your first question is borderline subjective. Your second is a matter of legality, which we don't address here. Please see the [help]. Advice: as you address this issue with either party, be sure to think things rather than feeling them. Feelings don't much matter in business.

Are we to infer this HVAC is located in an attic space above the fallen ceiling? Building code requires extra precautions against condensate leakage when the HVAC unit is located in a place where leakage could cause building damage. There are options as to how the extra protection can be implemented, but secondary drain, water sensor, and external drain pan are among the choices. All that insulation sitting on the downstream side of the coil suggests somebody was pretty careless in their work while ducts were disconnected.

This was VERY helpful. Thank you. Yes, the HVAC is in the attic. It was placed with permit but, in my experience, that doesn't mean much around here.

It is not uncommon for AC drain lines to become clogged.
The Tech would be expected to check the line and clear it if it was clogged. Inspecting the evaporator would not be normal, because the issue of a clogged line is what is being addressed.
The collapse of the ceiling was from multiple issues. I would say the tech that didn't make sure the line was connected was at fault as well as the contractor that allowed debris to get in the Air handler causing the obstructions.
You may get more action if you make a claim against both companies and they realize they can share the repair cost.  Both should have insurance for these type of occurrences.  You could file a claim with your insurance to possibly get a quicker repair, then your Ins.Co. will file against the others.
( I am not a lawyer, nor have I played one on TV.)

Thank you for your thoughts. They helped me to clarify mine. I subsequently edited my original post with the following: The system worked for 8 months, post contractor's failure to protect the coils. It then went from a slow drip one day, to being so saturated that the ceiling in two rooms collapsed, in less than 24 hours, during which the HVAC installer was the only one there.
